# Need a result with MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am implementing an messenger like what's app on social networking website where user can first send and messenger request to other user and he will accept the request and after accepting both users can do an chat. I have an table for confirming as an contact called `message_contacts` with following structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `evpos_message_contacts` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `request_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `accepted_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_accepted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I have another table for message conversation where users can communicate called

Messages having the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `evpos_messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('text','audio','image') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  `fromuser` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `touser` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isread` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `msg_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to get only one message from the above tables with latest one

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT` to get only one row and `ORDER BY column_name DESC` to get the last message

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY table_name_id DESC LIMIT 1
```